# Sorting out data from SQL in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to get some specific data out of my database but I've searching online and can't find how to do this (probably because I'm searching for the wrong terms).

I start with getting all the participants with a specific id like this : 
`contributions = Participant.where(user_id: params[:id])`

This will give me a `json` result like this :

```
0: {id_request: "1", user_id: "titivermeesch@gmail.com"}
1: {id_request: "2", user_id: "titivermeesch@gmail.com"}
```

So here I have all the requests (there is a `Request` class) that have that specific `user_id`.

Now I want to do this : 
`all = Request.where(id: id_request)`

This obviously don't work but how would I get all those `requests` that have all those id's that come from the first database query?

So with the results above I should get `Request` 1 and 2, but how? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: How are the models connected? Please show the `has_many` and `belongs_to` between both models.

Comment: I didn't use associations but I'm going to read about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
contributions = Participant.where(user_id: params[:id])
# Assuming the above is an active record query and id_request is a property of Participant
all = Request.where(id: contributions.map(&:id_request))
```

This is the equivalent of the SQL

```
select * from requests where id in (array_of_request_ids)
```

Comment: using `pluck` is probably preferred here and will save you an additional query.

Comment: @JoshBrody yes that is true if contributions (the variable) is not otherwise used. If it is used otherwise then pluck could cause extra queries.

Answer (score 1):

**If** You added associations in your model? it's very easy to retrieve the records

This should work:

```
 Request.joins(:participants).where("participants.user_id = ?", params[:id])
```

Also you might want to read the [following part](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/137/nodes/768) (on joins)

Comment: I will have to investigate in associations but this will really help me out.